# Is there / should there be a way of subscribing / unsubscribing to events with C# 6's null conditional?

Tags: c#, events

C# 6 saw the introduction of the `null conditional` operator and a specific syntax combining it with event firing (`Invoke()` was introduced specifically to allow null conditionals to work with events):

```
SomeEvent?.Invoke(...);
```

It seems to me that it would be useful to apply the null-conditional to the adding and removing of event delegates as well:

```
SomeProperty?.SomeEvent += SomeDelegate;
```

This doesn't work because the `+=` operator throws a null reference exception if `SomeProperty?.SomeEvent` evaluates to `null`.

In a similar manner to the use of `Invoke()`, we *could* write:

```
SomeProperty?.SomeEvent.Add(SomeDelegate);
```

I briefly wondered if this would work because the `+=` and `-=` operators are just shorthand for `Add` and `Remove` methods that are implicitly or explicitly defined for the event, but of course it doesn't (I don't think you can directly call `Add()` or `Remove()`).

My questions are:

1. Have I missed something that means I can already do something equivalent to this (i.e. without using `if (SomeProperty != null) { }`).
2. Could this or similar syntax be safely added to the language?

There could be the same saving in typing / obfuscation that seems to have motivated null conditionals in the first place:

```
Some?.Chain?.Of?.Properties?.SomeEvent += SomeDelegate;
```

---

**Edit**

It occurred to me to try the (somewhat clumsy):

```
SomeProperty?.SomeEvent ?? new EventHandler((o, e) => { }) += ...
```

with the expectation that the `new EventHandler` would be removed quickly or even optimised away completely as no reference to it is kept, but the compiler complains that "The event `SomeEvent` can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=". Probably just as well: I don't want my code to look like this!

Comment: Sounds like a good idea except for two things 1) Most events are declared static which imply a state, in particular, you have an instance of the class or 2) Non static local events by default mean that there is an instance of the class.  I'm not sure but I wouldn't expect the compiler to want to handle those two conditions.  Just my opinion.

Comment: @JohnPeters 1) Did you mean *non*-static? I think I disagree (if I've understood you): I'm no more or less likely to be interested in events on an object of questionable existence than I am any other property of it (where I can already use the null conditional). 2) If by "local event" you mean "in the same class", (i.e. `this?.SomeEvent`) then the only thing the compiler needs to do is ignore the conditional operator because `this?` will clearly always be non-null. In my experience, events are less typically consumed within the declaring class.

Comment: OK I see your point now, I think you are speaking of an Event declaration that others use who may or may not have hooked an event handler.   I was thinking about a declared event in a class that handles that event.    Makes more sense now as certainly there are legitimate null events hanging around everywhere.

Comment: I'm speaking of (potentially) hooking an event handler inside a nullable type variable where the variable could legitimately be null. If that's what you mean, then yes!

Comment: I'm surprised that you say "*This doesn't work because the `+=` operator throws a null reference exception if `SomeProperty?.SomeEvent` evaluates to `null`.*" I get a compile-time error: "The event 'INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=".

Comment: @PeterTaylor Hmmm. Yes - that is now what I get. I wonder if the behaviour of the compiler has changed in one of the updates to VS that has occurred since I wrote the question? Either that or I made a mistake, but I'm pretty sure I tried everything out.